# Multiple Capture Groups While Ignoring a Single Character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of random characters between A and z, such as `tahbAwgubsuregbbu` and I can easily capture between `{1,n}` characters before a `s` with `([A-z]{1,8})s`, but now I am trying to ignore a single (or multiple characters) before the `s` is matched. For example in the string above, I want to exclude any `w` characters. I understand I can't "jump" over the `w` with a capture group and return `tahbAgub`, but could I create two capture groups where the concatenation of those two groups is `{1,n}` characters, such as 1. `tahbA` 2. `gub`?

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/dD6fY9/1)

Comment: cant you replace `w` by empty string and then use the captured group?

Comment: `[A-z]` doesn't match what you think. For example it matches also `[ \ ] ^ _ ` *(see the ascii table)*

Comment: This? https://regex101.com/r/bL8bI1/1

Comment: I'm not absolutely clear on what you want to achieve, but what about a `split` on `w` and then a `join` without separator (i.e. `''`)?

Comment: You could use a [non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) to skip over the text you want to avoid.

Comment: @Shafizadeh that does work, thanks, but is there any way to ensure each capture group is a max of `n` characters, say `8`? Sometimes the sample strings are >25,000 characters, so I just want a small subset.

Comment: First thing to do is split on `s`. Then loop the resulting array removing the characters you don't want, like replace(/[chars]+/, '')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(.{0,8})?w(.{0,8})?s/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL8bI1/2)

---

According to [this comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520905/multiple-capture-groups-while-ignoring-a-single-character/36521055#comment-60647170), maybe you need to split your string. Something like this:

```js
var str = "tftftfwtahbAwgubsuregbbu";
var res = str.split(/w|s/);
document.write(res);
```

Comment: thanks! This works well; is there an easy way to tweak this so that it ignores an `w` character and creates `n` capture groups? For example `tftftfwtahbAwgubsuregbbu` would return three capture groups 1. `tftftf` 2. `tahbA`  3. `gub`?

Comment: @hotshotiguana I added another approach to my answer.